# report mailing date and time have expired

Tags: cron, mailing, scheduled-job

I can not send the mailing, in the report this message:  "Delivery has not yet begun for this mailing. If the scheduled delivery date and time is past, ask the system administrator or technical support contact for your site to verify that the automated mailer task ('cron job') is running - and how frequently." what am I doing wrong? What should I correct? Thank you
And if the problem is geolocation? And if the problem was the google API?
I also had difficulty understanding OpenStreetMaps, maybe I was wrong with them?
Is anyone practical with OpenStreetmap? Thanks
In setting mapping I put this indicated in the screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this can happen when your 'user' timezone and your server or site timezone are out of kilter

Comment: I found this article: can it be useful for the problem? 
https://blog.wikimedia.org/2018/06/05/improved-geocoding-in-civicrm/

Comment: where to set the time zone? Thanks

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with geocoding if i understand your question. i think i misunderstood your question first time and i expect it has nothing to do with timezone. do you have the Scheduled Job set to run - and is your cron running?

Comment: a message arrives on my email once a day which says that the cron is ok :   --2018-07-03 00:00:02--  https://crm.teatronecessariogenova.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=admin
Resolving crm.teatronecessariogenova.org (crm.teatronecessariogenova.org)... 178.63.119.153
Connecting to crm.teatronecessariogenova.org (crm.teatronecessariogenova.org)|178.63.119.153|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘-q’
     0K        14.3M=0s     
2018-07-03 00:00:02 (14.3 MB/s) - ‘-q’ saved [145]

Comment: it is not clear to me if the cron is running,  I see a red line in civiCRM system status

Comment: I acted on the cPanel putting the execution 1 time a day, with this code:  wget -O -q -t 1 https://crm.teatronecessariogenova.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=admin pass=C2R7XF2RP%Y2t)@e6wrE8M8u&key=81ff43f3ae0fa27398a88b4af57c0dab - - - - -  THANKS

Comment: "I see a red line in civiCRM system status" - what does this mean? Can you paste the message

Comment: ok, how can I put an image in a comment? With CTRL + G I failed - thank you

Comment: probably better if you Edit the original question and add new info and images in there so everyone notices

Comment: or if you are feeling really stuck - i can probably spend 10 mins on a skype call just to get you moving on this peter.davis59 - i am in NZ so need to find a time that works for both our timezones

Comment: ok, thanks petednz, I add the image of my cron, above: in my original question; and I thank you for your help proposal on skipe, but I'm in Italy and my spoken English is really bad !

Answer (score 1):

If your cron is not running then there is nothing to 'tell' the Scheduled Jobs (which starts the mailing job) to run.

As a quick fix you should be able to go to your Scheduled Jobs (Admin > System > Scheduled Jobs, or /civicrm/admin/job?reset=1 in Drupal), find the Mailings scheduler job and use 'Execute Now' under the 'More' option - this should cause any overdue Mailings to be sent out.

To set up a cron so that the Jobs run automatically you need to follow the instructions here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/

You also need to set any relevant Scheduled Jobs to be 'enabled' (under More)

Comment: thank Petednz, yes, I have already done this manual operation (Admin> System> Scheduled Jobs, find the Mailings planning job and use 'Run Now' under the 'Other' option) but this is a manuale sistem, I have already set all following the guide : https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs

Comment: I have problems sending for mailings, the message is: "Delivery has not yet begun for this mailing. If the scheduled delivery date and time is past, ask the system administrator or technical support contact for your site to verify that the automated mailer task ('cron job') is running - and how frequently."